# Rails Migration : adding an extra column to the table for which records are already loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2.3.8. I had created a migration for a table called `user` which currently has plenty of records.

Now the requirement is to add a new column to it.

I had to create a new migration file since rollback would delete the other table data. But adding a new migration did not work.

```
def self.up
     add_column "users", "xyz", :string, :default => "0"
end
```

What might be the reason?

- is it because the data is already loaded?
- is it something to do with caching?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use the generator? If the timestamp is older than what the original migration file was, it won't do anything.

Comment: Yes,i have used the generator to create the new migration....script/generate migration add_xyz_to_users.

Comment: Timestamp looks fine ...

Comment: I did User.reset_collumn_information the problem got solved .Resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @elmt's comment, you should create migrations using the command in your rails root directory:

```
script/generate migration <your_migration_name>
```

So in your case that would be something like this:

```
script/generate migration add_xyz_to_users
```

This will create a filename of the form `db/migrate/20101122183814_add_xyz_to_users.rb`. That's where you should add your migration. If the filename is not named correctly, the migration will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Ben pointed out correctly. That might be due to older migration version number. But can you tell which type of error are you facing? And is it during running migration or what?